# Assign new string in the beginning of a text in a specific row and column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying this for a while now, is there a possible way to append a new word in the beginning of the text in a specific row and column. For an example;

```
Body
 .
 .
 .
John, where are you?
```

Desired output:

```
Body
.
.
.
Hello John, where are you?
```

I've tried with:

```
rowIndex = df.index[109]
df.loc[rowIndex , 'Body'].append.str[:0].('Hello')
```

It didn't work however, appreciate your suggestion on this and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `+` for prepend new string:

```
df.loc[rowIndex , 'Body'] = 'Hello ' +  df.loc[rowIndex , 'Body']
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Body':['','','John, where are you?']}, index=[100,200,300])
print (df)
                     Body
100                      
200                      
300  John, where are you?

rowIndex = df.index[2]
df.loc[rowIndex , 'Body'] = 'Hello ' +  df.loc[rowIndex , 'Body']
print (df)
                           Body
100                            
200                            
300  Hello John, where are you?
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, however, it override the text in the given row. Row 109 only left with 'Hello' instead of 'Hello John, where are you?' should, I include .str[:0] ?

Comment: @SyafiqRosli - Added sample data, `str[:0]` is not necessary

Comment: my mistake, it works with your suggestion! thanks :)